# Restoring MongoDB replicaset member

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, mongodb-replica-set

Something happened with mongodb replicaset in kubernetes cluster after primary restarts.
I deployed mongodb replicaset using bitnami helm chart a month ago and it worked fine.
I have the following setup:

1. mongo-rs-0 (primamry)
2. mongo-rs-1 (secondary)
3. arbiter

In this installation authentication was enabled. But today something happened... One of the replicas with arbiter changed configuration and now the secondary has been detached somehow from my rs. I checked the data path in my secondary and it has 505MB, but my primary has 25+ GB of data.
Can I just re-add my detached mongo instance to replicaset?

Comment: Stop the secondary, delete all files/folder in `dbPath`, restart the secondary. It will perform an initial synch, I. E. copies all data from the primary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have this deployed using Kubernetes you can do the following:

1. delete the PVC claimed by `mongo-rs-1`. You can find this by describing the pod `kubectl describe po mongo-rs-1`. The volume name will be listed under volumes and type `PersistentVolumeClaim`
2. delete the pod `mongo-rs-1`. Wait a little bit for the PVC to be recreated. When the pod schedules the PVC will be recreated but the pod may not find the PVC because it was created *after* the pod was scheduled
3. Delete the pod once so it can find the PVC

Comment: Thanks for feedback! Are you sure it is gonna work? Because when I did `rs.status()` mongo-rs-1 wasn't listed there as a rs member. I want to be sure because it is production environment

Comment: @FoxyJS are you running `rs.status()` against `mongo-rs-0`? Can you list which helm chart you used to install MongoDB? As well as any custom values you overwrote during the installation

Comment: Today I solved it. I think the problem was with my first setup. When I installed mongo helm chart, secondary somehow did not catch up so my setup became: primary with arbiter. I did `rs.conf()` and `rs.status()` on secondary and it was not initialized yet. So I removed the arbiter and then added secondary with arbiter again. Everything works now, but my secondary has 14 Gb of data while primary has 25Gb... I dont know why is that so big difference? I counted docs withins collections and it seems okay...